# WSO2 EI 6.4.0 - Mitigating Cross Site Scripting Attacks

Tags: wso2, xss, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have done mitigations steps by follows this [WSO2 Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Mitigating+Cross+Site+Scripting+Attacks) to avoid Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks in WSO2 EI 6.4.0.

In below mentioned files i have made required changes as mentioned [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Mitigating+Cross+Site+Scripting+Attacks)

- edited `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml`
- Added the some configuration within the `<Hosts>` element of the `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml` file.

Post restarting server, I have noticed couple of things as mentioned below

- We're unable to modify artifacts like API, Sequence, task Scheduler via wso2 management console, But we can upload CARs, Connectors etc.

Whenever I try to edit files in management console, got below ERROR in logs

```
    [2022-10-18 07:38:59,904] [-1234] [] [http-nio-9443-exec-34] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve
} -  Could not handle request: /carbon/sequences/save_sequence.jsp                                                  
javax.servlet.ServletException: Possible XSS Attack. Suspicious code : eval($)                                      
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.valve.XSSValve.validateParameters(XSSValve.java:110)                                  
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.valve.XSSValve.invoke(XSSValve.java:86)                                               
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)              
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)                  
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)                   
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)        
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)                          
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.
java:159)                                                                                                           
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)                                
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)    
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)                        
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)                              
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)              
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)          
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)                      
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)                        
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)                          
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)                          
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)                       
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

- In DSS, we could able to edit in management console(eg. adding new operation) , but newly added operation is not available when i do `try it` option

Concluding that whatever we want, we can do via CAR, this mitigation change is not allow us to edit config files via management console.

Is my understanding correct or Am I missing something to notice? I just need to know what was the product level impacts post this Mitigation.

Kindly clarify my doubt or share your thoughts on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to skip the content validation of the artifact files. We can whitelist the resource paths used to modify artifacts such as API, Sequences etc. To do this you need to add the following patterns under the `<Patterns>` element of the `<XSSPreventionConfig>` element in `carbon.xml` config file.

```xml
<XSSPreventionConfig>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Rule>allow</Rule>
    <Patterns>
        <Pattern>carbon/sequences</Pattern>
        <Pattern>carbon/configadmin</Pattern>
        <Pattern>carbon/localentries</Pattern>
        <Pattern>carbon/api</Pattern>
        <Pattern>carbon/proxyservices</Pattern>
        <Pattern>carbon/resources</Pattern>
        <Pattern>carbon/task</Pattern>
    </Patterns>
</XSSPreventionConfig>
```

Reference: http://ravindraranwala.blogspot.com/2015/10/preventing-xss-and-csrf-vulnerabilities.html